# How to update React in a project created using Create React App?

Tags: reactjs

I have a project created with Create React App. The documentation regarding how to update the React version seems to be pretty poor.

There is some documentation here https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/updating-to-new-releases . This seems ambiguous though - are these instructions just to update CRA itself and `react-scripts`? I have followed the instructions - my `react-scripts` is up to date at v2.1.1, but my React version is only 16.5.2 - I need 16.6 for a certain feature.

Comment: As per my knowledge, react-scripts internally uses react package. For every react package, react-scripts updates (by community). So if you want to externally use react package you need to eject from CRA and use that.

Comment: So react-scripts updates the React version? If so, how do I then use it? This is all really unclear.

Answer (score 7):

Updating react-scripts will not update your React version, you need to do that yourself by updating both react and react-dom (must be the same). Check [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6351#issuecomment-461101177) and [this](https://www.kirupa.com/react/updating_react_version.htm). I was confused about this too!

Answer (score 0):

Along with updating react and react-dom you will also need to update some of the other libraries too like react-router-dom.

If the other libraries are not upgraded it may cause conflicts between library versions while installing node modules.

so while migrating react application to new version you should also update other library versions and change node js version to latest recommanded too.

And after the updates you will need to make some of the changes in your code. for Ex. Routing structure, and check if any hooks or inbuilt features are not removed by react.